# I've problem with Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
NSLog(@"%@",selectedImage);
if (self.selectedImage != nil) {

    UIImage *img = self.selectedImage;
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   img, @"picture",
                                   @"iOS Apps with FBConnect",@"caption",
                                   nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos/Wall"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
    [img release];
}
```

I've this code.,
I use Facebook graph API for post photo to my wall.
but Photo has been upload to other album

Can I select album to upload photo ?? 
or
I'd like my photo upload into "Wall Photos" album ??

Comment: Note: Please use a more descriptive and less generic title for your questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637514/facebook-ios-sdk-trouble-posting-photo-using-uiimage/6698004#6698004 have a look at this.