# Uploading UIImage with FBDialog

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'd like to use the `FBDialog` from the Facebook SDK, but it seems like it only takes an URL for posting images. Is there any way to upload an `UIImage` to Facebook using the `FBDialog`  without uploading the image to another server before posting?

I'm currently using this to post an `UIImage` on facebook:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"A caption", @"caption",
                               nil];
[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:nil];
```

It works great, but I need the `FBDialog` . Is there any way to do same thing with the `FBDialog`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to post a `UIImage` you cannot directly attach it. Here are two methods:

1. Is too upload to a server and then take a URL/request/query to that server
2. (A more practical approach) Upload to your Facebook user's album and then post that picture

For more in-depth tutorial look at this link:

[Official Facebook iOS Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

[This is a similar question with a great answer  that provides step by step tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637514/facebook-ios-sdk-trouble-posting-photo-using-uiimage)

Comment: Thank you. I decided to use the second method. The "request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result"'s request object contains the id for the uploaded picture. That can be posted in the FBDialog afterwards as https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=THE_ID_HERE

Comment: Well, I just received an error trying to post this URL. "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream.". It turns out Facebook doesn't allow posting of URLs to images hosted on Facebook anymore.
http://www.syndicatedmethods.com/SyndicatedBlogs/post/2010/06/22/FBCDN-image-is-not-allowed-in-stream-How-can-this-be.aspx

Comment: Really? Well, I would say wait for iOS 6 to publicly release in October and use the Social framework to share to Facebook just like the twitter API. In fact, if you are part of the iOS developer program like me you can get some hands on!

Comment: Now we can directly attach an image, see below answers

Answer (score 2):

As of Facebook iOS SDK v3.13+, you can `presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams` to upload an image directly from the device. See the example code below:

```
FBShareDialogPhotoParams *photoParams = [FBShareDialogPhotoParams new];
UIImage *screenshot = //image you want to share.
photoParams.photos = @[screenshot];
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:photoParams
                                 clientState:nil
                                     handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

                                     }];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) feedDialogButtonClicked {
NSMutableDictionary *params = 
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Testing Feed Dialog", @"name",
        @"Feed Dialogs are Awesome.", @"caption",
        @"Check out how to use Facebook Dialogs.", @"description",
        @"http://www.example.com/", @"link",
        @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
        nil];  
[facebook dialog:@"feed"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];
```

}

from the official Facebook iOS Tutorial, as posted by Rohan

Comment: The question is about **uploading** an image from the device not posting with a link to an image.